# GTK2+ error: GTK_IS_CONTAINER & GTK_IS_WIDGET failed

Tags: c, gtk

It's my first post here, I made this account because I'm kind of stumped.
I'm trying to practise passing structures as arguments to callbacks, and for that purpose I created a simple program with a button in a window. In the first iteration, pressing the button with label "Button 1" will change it into a different button with label "Button 2", while in the second the change is done by hovering over the buttons.
Below is the code for the first iteration

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *button2;
GtkWidget *window;
} example;

void callback_func (GtkWidget *ignored, example *test) {
GtkWidget *window=test->window;
GtkWidget *changebutton1=test->button1;
GtkWidget *changebutton2=test->button2;
gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(window),changebutton1);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),changebutton2);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}
void callback_func2 (GtkWidget *ignored, example *test) {
GtkWidget *window=test->window;
GtkWidget *changebutton1=test->button1;
GtkWidget *changebutton2=test->button2;
gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(window),changebutton2);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),changebutton1);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
example test;
gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
GtkWidget *window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
GtkWidget *changebutton1=gtk_button_new_with_label("Button 1");
GtkWidget *changebutton2=gtk_button_new_with_label("Button 2");

test.window=window;
test.button1=changebutton1;
test.button2=changebutton2;

g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);


gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),changebutton1);
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (changebutton1), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (callback_func), (gpointer*)&test);
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (changebutton2),"clicked",G_CALLBACK(callback_func2),(gpointer*)&test);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);

gtk_main ();
return 0;
}
```

When running the above code, by clicking the button once, the buttons switch properly, but when I click it again (now calling callback_func2 instead of callback_func, which are essentially identical save for the buttons switching place) I get this:
(gtktesting.exe:92024): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_add: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

If I replace the "clicked" events with "enter_notify_event" and "leave_notify_event", the first change fails as well, now yielding more errors.

Anybody know what's going on?

Also, a bonus question. I pretty much copied and pasted the base of this code from another post, since I had been trying to write it by myself unsuccessfully and I wanted to test if it works at all. I noticed that the second argument in the callbacks is "example *test". Can anybody explain the "example" type? It's only the name of the stucture, and I've no idea what it's doing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Try:

```
test.window  = g_object_ref(window);
test.button1 = g_object_ref(changebutton1);
test.button2 = g_object_ref(changebutton2);
```

**Full explaination**

Objects (i.e. subclasses of `GObject`) in GTK+ are reference counted. That means, every object (e.g. Widget) has "reference count" - number of pointers that point to it. When number reaches 0 - object is deallocated. Objects are created with reference count of 1. As C does not have smart pointers C++ does nor anything similar, reference counting has to be done manually. User has to call `g_object_ref` in order to retain a reference (I use words "pointer" and "reference" interchangeably), and `g_object_unref` when user is done with a reference. That ensures that no object is destroyed while being in use.

`GtkWidget` is special, as it begins life with "floating" reference. That means that first time widget is referenced its reference count does not increase - its "floating" reference is "sunk". After that it behaves like any other `GObject`.

When you create your buttons, they are created with reference count 1 ("floating"). When they are added to their container, their references are still 1 (but "sunk"). This means, buttons are *owned* by the container that they're added to.

Now, when you remove button from container:

```
gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(window),changebutton1);
```

reference count for `changebutton1` is decreased, drops to 0, which forces object destruction, and `test.button1` is now dangling pointer.

To overcome this, use `g_object_ref` anytime you want to store pointer to `GObject`. That way you express "`test` participates in ownership of `changebutton1`" (or, "`test` is interested in keeping `changebutton1` alive).

When you are done with `window`, `button1` and `button2`, call `g_object_unref` on them.

**Bonus question**

> Also, a bonus question. I pretty much copied and pasted the base of
>   this code from another post, since I had been trying to write it by
>   myself unsuccessfully and I wanted to test if it works at all. I
>   noticed that the second argument in the callbacks is "example *test".
>   Can anybody explain the "example" type? It's only the name of the
>   stucture, and I've no idea what it's doing there.

`example` is defined here:

```
typedef struct {
GtkWidget *button1;
GtkWidget *button2;
GtkWidget *window;
} example; // declares type "example"
```

`GObject` signal system is designed in a sucha way that it allows passing arbitrary pointer as a last argument to callback, so a programmer can pass extra information from place where signal connection is created (`g_signal_connect`), to a callback.

Comment: Thank you! I had just found out about reference before I read your answer, but your input will help anyobody else with the same problem. However, I still have a problem when setting the callback to trigger on mouse hover over the button. If I only change "clicked" to "enter_notify_event" or "leave_notify_event", the program just stops working.

Comment: @Sotos I apparently fixed this one too. For anyone interested, "enter_notify_event" is wrong when talking about buttons, the event is just "enter".

Comment: @Sotos: actually the [enter_notify_event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-enter-notify-event) is the right way, since the GtkButton [enter signal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-enter) has been long deprecated (since 2.8). But you need to use a callback with a different prototype than the one you have presented (see above, the "enter_notify_event" link).